# Leaflet circlemarker with shadow

Tags: leaflet, style

I am often creating hex grid layers in Leaflet which use circlemarker for styling.

[image]

I would like to shift / offset the shadow circle under each marker in order to give the layer some depth.

[image]

Which would be the best way to achieve this?

Could I possibly create a style function which creates two circlemarker for each feature with the lower circle being shifted and opaque.

I could just duplicate the layer. But how can I apply a shift to a layer or a circlemarker?

At the moment I just add a second layer with a lat/lon shift to the elements based on the zoom level.

```
var gridZoomShift = {
  12: 0.0004,
  13: 0.0002,
  14: 0.0001,
  15: 0.00005,
  16: 0.000025,
  17: 0.0000125
};
```

Not perfect but good enough for now.

[image]

I chose in the end the L.divIcon solution due to browser compatibility with filter:drop-shadow.

```
new L.geoJson(dots, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, divStyle(feature));
  }
}).addTo(map_geodata);

function divStyle(feature){
    var c = feature.properties.c;

    var s = c < circleRadiusArray[0] ? 4 :
        c < circleRadiusArray[1] ? 4.5 :
            c < circleRadiusArray[2] ? 5 :
                c < circleRadiusArray[3] ? 5.5 :
                    c < circleRadiusArray[4] ? 6 :
                        c < circleRadiusArray[5] ? 6.5 :
                            c < circleRadiusArray[6] ? 7 :
                                c < circleRadiusArray[7] ? 7.5 :
                                    c < circleRadiusArray[8] ? 8 :
                                        c < circleRadiusArray[9] ? 8.5 :
                                            9;

    return {
        icon: L.divIcon({
            className: 'circle',
            iconSize: [s, s]
        })
    };
}
```

[image]

The style for a bivariate map:

```
function divStyle(feature){
    var c = feature.properties.c;
    var v = feature.properties.v;

    var s = c < circleRadiusArray[0] ? 4 :
            c < circleRadiusArray[1] ? 4.5 :
            c < circleRadiusArray[2] ? 5 :
            c < circleRadiusArray[3] ? 5.5 :
            c < circleRadiusArray[4] ? 6 :
            c < circleRadiusArray[5] ? 6.5 :
            c < circleRadiusArray[6] ? 7 :
            c < circleRadiusArray[7] ? 7.5 :
                                       8.5;

    var circle_colour = v < circleColorArray[0] ? 'circle_c51b7d' :
                        v < circleColorArray[1] ? 'circle_de77ae' :
                        v < circleColorArray[2] ? 'circle_f1b6da' :
                        v < circleColorArray[3] ? 'circle_fde0ef' :
                        v < circleColorArray[4] ? 'circle_f7f7f7' :
                        v < circleColorArray[5] ? 'circle_e6f5d0' :
                        v < circleColorArray[6] ? 'circle_b8e186' :
                        v < circleColorArray[7] ? 'circle_b8e186' :
                                                  'circle_4d9221';

    return {
        icon: L.divIcon({
            className: circle_colour,
            iconSize: [s, s]
        })
    };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very similar answer to IvanSanchez, but you could switch from `L.CircleMarker` and use [`L.DivIcon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#divicon) to instead create your circle completely with CSS:

```
.circle {
  background: #0000ff; /* color of the circle */
  border-radius: 50%; /* make the div a circular shape */
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px grey; /* see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_shadows.asp */
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px grey;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px grey;
}
```

HTML:

```
var div_circle = L.divIcon({ className: 'circle'})
var marker = L.marker([51.509, -0.08], {icon: div_circle} ).addTo(mymap);
```

Here's an (updated) demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lna57q3m/1/

Comment: That's pretty smart. The webkit-box-shadow does work on Chrome.

Comment: Thanks.  :)  I just changed the CSS slightly (horizontal and vertical offset changed from 10px to 4px) so that the shadow is aligned more like your image above (updated fiddle, too).

Comment: How would you size the circle?

Comment: Don't worry. I worked it out with iconSize. Let me update my demo.

Comment: You can have a look how it works in action on my dev server. It's the Media and Communications layer (only on Desktop) http://atap.geolytix.net/?geodata

Comment: That was a hell of a long day, but I got there. Wouldn't have been able to hack this without your help. Thanks a lot. Are you going to FOSS4G? Ping me for beers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `L.SVG` renderer, you can use some CSS (as [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13624469)) and the `className` option of the `L.CircleMarker`s to achieve this.

e.g.:

```
<style>
.shadow {
  filter: drop-shadow( 5px 2px 5px #000 );
}
</style>
```

and then

```
var marker = L.circleMarker(myCenter, {
  className: 'shadow'
});
map.addLayer(marker);
```

See a working example at https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/duyu/edit?html,output

If you are using a `L.Canvas` renderer for your points, you'll have to create duplicate elements.

Comment: Hi Ivan, great to hear from you. This works great on FF but I am having problem with the drop shadow on Chrome. I added a -webkit-filter but this doesn't seem to work. Have you got the example to work in Chrome?

Comment: No. Apparently support for this feature is not complete across all browsers.

Comment: No problem I got this to work with the L.divIcon solution + -webkit-box-shadow. Thanks anyways. Remind me to buy you a beer at the next FOSS4G.